# PyQt Change Direction of QWidget from right to left

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qwidget

I would like to change a direction of widget From Right to left by using SetLyouatDirection but does not work
This my result :

[image]

this my code :

```
for item in listConcrdance:
        c+=1
        widgitItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        widgetText=QtGui.QLabel(str(c)+". "+item[1]+" ("+self.process.convertNumberToNameOFSorat(item[0][1])+":"+item[0][2]+")")
        widgetText.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        widgetLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetText)
        widgetLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
        widget.setLayout(widgetLayout)
        self.listWidgetQuran.addItem(widgitItem)
        widgitItem.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint())
        self.listWidgetQuran.setItemWidget(widgitItem, widget)
```

Comment: Try applying your `setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)` on your `widgetLayout` like `widgetLayout.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)`

Comment: AttributeError: 'QHBoxLayout' object has no attribute 'setLayoutDirection'

Comment: sorry I meant `widgetLayout.setDirection(QtGui.QBoxLayout.RightToLeft)` instead of `setLayoutDirection` : [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#setDirection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[your_label].setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        for item in range(10):
            widgitItem = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
            widget = QtGui.QWidget()
            widgetText = QtGui.QLabel(str(item))
            if item % 2 == 0:
                widgetText.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
            else:
                widgetText.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
            widgetLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
            widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetText)
            widget.setLayout(widgetLayout)
            widgitItem.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint())
            self.listWidget.setItemWidget(widgitItem, widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this is not exactly the right answer. The text here is Arabic (an RTL language). Changing alignment != changing direction. Text direction should be changed as well to RTL. With the current answer punctuation, parentheses etc, will be reversed